# Xpath search string to cts:search

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to use the Xpath **string** user input in cts:search query to get the matching nodes from the database.

Sample query used :

```
let $query := "/book/chapter/chapter-meta/meta/meta-value[.='book-title']"
let $results :=  cts:search($query, cts:and-query(()), (), 0.0)
return $results
```

The above one is throwing error as XDMP-UNSEARCHABLE, so I tried

```
let $query := "/book/chapter/chapter-meta/meta/meta-value[.='book-title']"
let $results :=  cts:search(xdmp:value($query), cts:and-query(()), (), 0.0)
return $results
```

and this also resulted in the same error.

But when the Xpath is passed directly to cts:search like below ,it is giving results

```
cts:search(/book/chapter/chapter-meta/meta/meta-value[.='book-title'], cts:and-query(()), (), 0.0)
```

Could you please suggest how to convert the Xpath string to a proper value for the cts:search to get results like the last query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need cts:search() in this case? You are evaluating direct XPATH without any collection or special handling. You should try: let $query := "/book/chapter/chapter-meta/meta/meta-value[.='book-title']" return xdmp:value($query)

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well, but for some other queries like "/book[descendant::chapter]", it is giving error as XDMP-EXPNTREECACHEFULL. The cts:search works for most of the queries,so chose that approach.

Comment: Cts search will not likely fix the expanded tree cache issue. Same data needs to be checked. Same result set given.  For this issue, you may need to return less content, paginate or look into searching via lexicons (range query) or an optic search where values were extracted and indexed via a TDE template.